# How to change block size of PHP FTP?

Tags: php, ftp

The problem is very slow transfer speed of ftp_put() command:

```
$ftp = ftp_connect( 'host' );
ftp_login( $ftp, 'user', 'password' );
ftp_pasv( $ftp, TRUE );
ftp_put( $ftp, 'local_file', 'remote_path', FTP_BINARY );
```

Transfer speed of 2MB file is about 15 sec, while WinSCP client uploads same file in 1-2 seconds.

So I suppose that's because my network connection have quite a big latency and file is being transfered in very small chunks.

How can i fix this?

Comment: Why should `WinSCP` showing less latency?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the PHP ftp_raw command:

```
ftp_raw($ftp_conn, "BLKSIZE=nnnn");
```

where nnnn is the block size you want to set.

Comment: Sorry, but this doesn't work for me.
Tried different values of nnnn with no success.

Comment: Your question was "How to change block size of PHP FTP?" The answer I provided does that. That it didn't solve your underlying problem means that block size was not the issue. Have you tried comparing the default settings of WinSCP and creating that same environment in PHP?